# Transform and store reversed order digits of an integer to a complete integer number

Tags: c

Input:

```
Enter an integer number: 1234567
```

Expected output:

```
7654321       // As a complete integer, not separate digits
```

I have tried by following this strategy: transform and store reversed order digits of an integer to a complete integer number:

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main(void){

int number=get_input_validation();
find_out_the_reverse_order_and_transform_digits_as_a_complete_integer(number);
  }
int get_input_validation(){
//Drop variables here
int number;

//Input validation
while(1){

//Taking input from the user
printf("Enter an integer number: ");
scanf("%d",&number);

int count=find_out_the_number_of_digit(number);

if(count>5 || count<5){
    printf("Only 5 digits are allowed here\n");
}
else{
    break;
}


}
return number;
}
int find_out_the_number_of_digit(int number){

int count=0;

//Getting total digits of a given number
while(number!=0){
    number=number/10;
    count++;


}
return count;
}

int find_out_the_reverse_order_and_transform_digits_as_a_complete_integer(int number){
 int complete_integer=0;
 int value=10000;

while(number!=0){
    int last_digit=0;

    //get the last digit
    last_digit=number%10;

    //get the quotient
    number=number/10;

    complete_integer=complete_integer+last_digit*value;
    value=value/10;

    //To display the last digit
    printf("%d",last_digit);

}
printf("\n");
printf("%d",complete_integer);
}
```

Now the problem is: This program works for only 5 digits like. From my code, I get the output like

Input:

```
12345
```

Output:

```
 54321     // As a complete integer, not separate digits
```

If I give the input like 123456 or 1234 means greater or less than five digits then It does not work. It works for only exacts 5 digits of an integer.

What I want to achieve: I want that my program will give the expected output for any digits of a given integer. How can I do that?

Comment: To be honest: I have made it by myself. Still, I am thinking about this problem. I have some limitations in asking questions. Because I am a new user on this platform.

Comment: Fun little exercise: now try it with a `float`

Comment: Ok, I am trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C it is good to write functions which do some separate tasks. Reversing the unsigned integer is very easy:

```
unsigned reverseUnsigned(unsigned val)
{
    unsigned result = 0;

    while(val)
    {
        result *= 10;
        result += val % 10;
        val /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}


int main(void)
{
    printf("reversed: %u\n", reverseUnsigned(1234567));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/E3s9c8

Bear in mind that it will not work if reversed value is too large to be stored in the unsigned int.

Comment: What about writing macros for functions that are calledvery often ? :)

Comment: @APJo Frequency does not matter. If you want to save the call instruction just make functions inline. Macros should be avoided when possible

Comment: is inlining a standard feature supported portably ? Also, honestly curious, why should macros be avoided ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your value of the value variable. At the moment you're telling the program to process 5 digits by setting value equal to 10^4, or 10000. Set the value to 10 to the power of (length of integer - 1):

```
int value=1;

for (int i = 1; i < find_out_the_number_of_digit(number); i++)
{
    value *= 10;
}
```